# Convert numbers to time in google spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to build an automated Google Sheets Spreadsheet where I can enter the date, clock-in, lunch time, clock-out, total worked hours per day and finally totalize all the hours worked in the month. It's not too difficult to create a working Time Sheet like that in Google Spreadsheet but there're a couple of improvements I'd love to make. One is even when the spreadsheet calculates the hours correctly for the day it displays the total as clock time, 8:22 PM, for instance instead of 8:22 hours. The other thing is this format forces me to write the hours in time format which is tedious. I'd like to type 3 or 4 digits into the cell and have it convert it to time for me.

I learned the only way to achieve this was with Google Apps Script so I followed the only tutorial I found on this but the code is just not working. The scripting utility uses javascript which I'm kind of familiar since I use it everyday in After Effects expressions but I'm hardly an expert. I'd love if someone could help me with this unchallenging (for you :D) project. Of course if anyone has a better alternative to anything I'm doing, I'm totally open to changing course. Thanks a lot. I'll paste the code I created following the tutorial and then the link to the tutorial itself.

```
var COLUMN_TO_CHECK = 3;
var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  if(sheet.getName() === SHEET_NAME){
    var selectedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

    selectedCell.setNumberFormat("@");

    if(selectedCell.getColumn() === COLUMN_TO_CHECK){
      var cellValue = selectedCell.getValue();
      var time = cellValue.substr(0,2)+":"+cellValue.substr(cellValue.lenght - 2);
      selectedCell.setValue(time);
      selectedCell.setNumberFormat("hh:mm");
     }
    }
  }
```

I'm getting an error at line 7: var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();. The debugger calls the variable **ss** to be null.

One thing I noticed about the tutorial is it's inconsistent between the featured code and the code you write step by step and they skip some lines of code too. Which could be the reason why my code is not working. I tried to carbon copy the featured code when following the tutorial sent me into dead ends.

https://yagisanatode.com/2018/06/02/google-apps-script-how-to-automatically-generate-a-time-from-a-four-digit-24-hour-time-in-google-sheets/

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: In `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` you implicitly assume there is an active sheet, but if you access it programmatically you may need to select a sheet instead.

Comment: Why not simply set the Format->Number->Duration?

Comment: You can use let ms = new Date().valueOf() - new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate()).valueOf(); Then ms is in milliseconds and you can use modulo arithmetic to determine number of hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for your interest in helping. I'm just looking to build a time sheet in Google Sheets to track my worked hours and totalize them by day and then sum them all up for the month total.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel yes after tweaking the code I found that leaving default values didn't work. I had to give the the sheet a name and use it in the code. I didn't want to make a simple thing complex but in the end that's what I needed to do.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted and the answerer is the author of your referring blog. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: @TheWizEd Can you be a little more specific? I don't know if you read it but I said I'm not an expert. However, analysing your answer a bit I guess it focuses on the final part of my request but not the main part. I need a way to enter 3 or 4 digit numbers in the cells and have Google Sheets automatically interpreting them as time. Like if typing "930" would give me "9:30 am" and "625" end up in "6:25 pm".

Comment: @MiMi That's an interesting approach, I don't know how I'd set it up in the spreadsheet though.

Comment: @Tanaike yes, I was really lucky the author of the tutorial actually answered. And I've progressed a lot since he did it. I don't know the etiquette here but I think having alternatives to reaching the goal would not hurt. Especially if someone new gets here looking for a way to do it. If it's not appropiate I apologize, I'm sure I can get to the solution I'm looking for with Yagisan's input.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of the article you referenced here. I don't use StackOverflow enough to add this to the comments which, as I am sure, would be the preference here.

Note that the `ss` variable references the active spreadsheet. This is the spreadsheet that is [bound to the script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions). Because we are using the [`onEdit()` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) this script needs to be bound to the Google Sheet. From your question, I am not certain if you have done this  or not, but here are the instructions to accomplish this:
In your Google Sheet menu go to > Extensions > Apps Script.

From here, paste in the code and save the project. Ensure that your sheet named (the one in the tab) is the same as the one you wish to modify and update the `SHEET_NAME` variable accordingly.

This should solve the error that you are facing.

Note - the code breakdown below the main code is only to highlight some important parts of the code, rather than be a step-by-step guide. I have updated the post with this in mind and appreciate the feedback.

My apologies if I have misunderstood your question.

*Tanaike - Please feel free to remove this reply or incorporate it into the comments rather than in here if you feel this would be more appropriate.*

Comment: Hi Yagisan, I didn't ever imagine this would reach you. That's awesome. First let me thank you for making that tutorial, taking the time to help others is something to be grateful for. Secondly, it may have been confusing for someone like me with intermediate knowledge of Javascript. I think begginers and intermediate users, need clear and consistent information throughtout our tutorials, I personally often write code unconfident of what I'm doing and having inconsistent info just hightens that insecurity and the feel you're not ever going to solve it.

Comment: Ok, it's kind of working. Whenever I enter a number it gets converted to a time format, however, it doesn't result in the expected value. For instance, if I write "930" the value entered is "12:30", if I write "12:55" I get "8:55". I tried changin my Locale in the sheet's settings to my actual city with no luck. Still getting the weird conversion. Also, for some reason, the last column in the array gets ignored to the code. I had an array of 4 columns and it worked on 3, I then added another and it began working on 4 and so on.

Comment: @SergioPol Not too sure what the cause is there, but if you have a sanitised version of the sheet, feel free to share the link here or via my contact page if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your solution.
Here is how it works for me:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //Get the active Spreadsheet and Sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var selectedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  
  if(selectedCell.getColumn() > 2 && selectedCell.getColumn() < 7 
      && selectedCell.getRow() > 7 && selectedCell.getRow() < 40) {

    //Ensure cell is set to text.
    selectedCell.setNumberFormat("@");
    var cellValue = selectedCell.getValue();

    //Get value as number
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(cellValue)) && isFinite(cellValue) && cellValue != 0) {
      
      // Split the first 2 characters and last two and put in a colon ":" in the middle.
      var time = cellValue.substr(0,2) + ":" + cellValue.substr(2);
      selectedCell.setValue(time);
      
    } else if (cellValue === '.' || cellValue === ',' || cellValue == '0') {
      // If you set '.' or ',' or '0' it sets the current time.
      selectedCell.setValue(new Date());
    }

    //Set the cell format to time. 
    selectedCell.setNumberFormat("HH:mm");

  }
}
```